# Limitation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a simple example of a 2x2 matrix. Let's say we assign two numbers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and for each of these numbers, a corresponding $x_1,x_2$ vectors with two values each and then assume that these are the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of some 2x2 square matrix.

How can we go about to prove that for arbitrary values of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, x_1,x_2$ a corresponding square matrix does not always exist? Also, general proof would be a lot better than for a set size.

Comment: a simple example is $x=0$, $\lambda\neq 0$

Comment: Another: $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2, \ x_1=\alpha x_2$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lean fairly heavily on diagonalisability here. Just let $V$ have columns $x_1$, $x_2$, $D$ have diagonal $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and let $A=VDV^{-1}$ be your matrix with these eigenvalues and eigenvectors. It works in all cases except those where $x_1$, $x_2$ are parallel, which you shouldn't be considering. It even works when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$, and generalises beyond the 2x2 case.

Comment: What do you mean by "it works in all cases....."?

Comment: I mean all values of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{C}$, $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{C}^2$.